# I want to make a mouse click on a scheduled time automatically

Tags: mouse

I'm now using Ubuntu 16.10 on my laptop and I want to know how to make a scheduled mouse click. I tried searching for google but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Try looking up `xdotool`

Comment: I tried to but how can I schedule `xdotool`?

Comment: If you want it to click very very frequently, run it in a `while` loop inside a script, with `sleep` for time delay. Otherwise, I think a cron job would work.

Comment: I added crontab -e`* * * * * xdotool mousemove 1290 400` to test if crontab works but it doesn't work. What's wrong with it?

Comment: A mouseclick on a random place or specific?

Comment: I want a mouseclick on a specific place as you can see from my previous comment

Comment: It sais what you added to crontab, the question sais nothing about position hence my question...

Comment: I'm sorry...... I didn't think about it.